# How to dynamically pivot a table in Spring JPA @Query?

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, pivot-table, recharts

I am working on a chart application that takes in data from a Spring API and visualizes it with React Recharts. I have the following table:

[image]

The media categories are not a fixed number so I cannot make a separate database column for each other. After skimming through a couple of other StackOverflow threads I managed to create this SQL that dynamically pivots the table:

```
use test;
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'ifnull(SUM(case when media_category = ''',
      media_category,
      ''' then printed_square_meters end),0) AS `',
      media_category, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  test;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT date, printer_id, ', @sql, '
                  FROM test
                   GROUP BY date, printer_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This is the result:
[image]
I am using a repository interface that extends `JpaRepository<MediaCategoryUsageEntity, Long>` and all my methods use a `@Query` annotation. So I tried to paste the SQL into the query annotation, but the server crashes with the following error:

```
2021-12-28 20:05:52.703 ERROR 22576 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'baseController' defined in file [/media/stoyank/Elements/University/Semester 3/group-project-cannon/API/build/classes/java/main/api/coloradodashboard/BaseController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'baseService' defined in file [/media/stoyank/Elements/University/Semester 3/group-project-cannon/API/build/classes/java/main/api/coloradodashboard/BaseService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mediaCategoryUsageRepository' defined in api.coloradodashboard.mediacategoryusage.MediaCategoryUsageRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List api.coloradodashboard.mediacategoryusage.MediaCategoryUsageRepository.getAllForPeriodAggregated(java.lang.String,java.util.Date,java.util.Date)! Reason: The string <SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
select count(GROUP) FROM media_category_usage
                   GROUP BY date, printer_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
> starts a quoted range at 134, but never ends it.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The string <SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

```
public interface MediaCategoryUsageRepository extends JpaRepository<MediaCategoryUsageEntity, Long> {
  @Query("sql statement here", nativeQuery = true)
  List<Object[]> getAll();
}
```

Recharts requires the data in the following format:

```
[
   {
      "date": "2021-12-01"
      "Paper": 23.39,
      "Canvas": 88.65,
      other categories: their printed square meters...
   },
   {
      "date": "2021-12-02"
      "Paper": 83.39,
      "Canvas": 811.65,
      other categories: their printed square meters...
   }, ...
]
```

**My question is**: Is it possible to make the pivoting work with the `@Query` annotation and possibly replace `Object[]` with a DTO(I am aware that native queries can be mapped to a DTO with `@SqlResultSetMapping`, but keep in mind that the media categories are of unknown number)?

If that is not possible, is it a bad idea to pass the data to the frontend as is - i.e.:

```
[
   {
      "date": "2021-12-09",
      "printer_id": "702"
      "media_category": "Paper",
      "printed_square_meters": 23.39
   },
   {
      "date": "2021-12-09",
      "printer_id": "702"
      "media_category": "Canvas",
      "printed_square_meters": 53.39
   }, ...
]
```

and transform the data there(frontend) in the required format and how can I achieve this? I tried using lodash's `groupBy()` and `mergeWith()`, but no success yet.

Comment: Perhaps this will help:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot